# Не работает вк метод photos.get

Tags: python, вконтакте, бот

```
import vk_botting

from settings import *
from commands.ocnovnoe import *
from other.welcome import *

bot = vk_botting.Bot(command_prefix='лео ')
bot.case_insensitive=None

res = await self.bot.vk_request('photos.get', owner_id=-group, album_id=279860010, access_token=TOKEN, v=5.131)


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

`

Как использовать `attach_user_token(TOKEN)`?

Пример какой то пожалуйста

Comment: В чем именно проблема? Код ошибки из консоли есть?

Comment: User token passed to group client

Comment: мне сказали использовать attach_user_token(TOKEN)
Но я не понимаю как

Comment: А "photos.get" не работает если подключаться через обычный токен группы, так выходит код ошибки вк 27, надо использовать юзер токен, а как я и сказал, юзер токен надо использовать через "attach_user_token(TOKEN)"

Comment: Так как у вас бот, понимания того как вы берете токен пользователя у меня нет, но в документации написано, что можно использовать сервеcный токен для вызова метода https://dev.vk.com/method/photos.get

Comment: {'error': {'error_code': 27, 'error_msg': 'Group authorization failed: method is unavailable with group auth.', 'request_params': [{'key': 'method', 'value': 'photos.get'}, {'key': 'oauth', 'value': '1'}, {'key': 'owner_id', 'value': 'owner_id'}, {'key': 'album_id', 'value': 'album_id'}, {'key': 'v', 'value': '5.131'}]}}

Comment: Я щас кинул, я щас использовал сервесный ключ доступа